# Invalid update data in two interrelated combobox

Tags: c#, ado.net, combobox

In the form of two combo box and a textbox. 1 cb is connected to the table through the Load startup gets their values​​:

```
this.cb1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.cb1);
SELECT id, name FROM cb1
```

2 cb is similar, but loading takes a parameter of the bound textbox (id contains the selected row cb1):

```
this.cb2TableAdapter.Fill(this.dbDataSet.cb2, Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
SELECT id, id_cb1 name FROM cb2 WHERE (id_cb1 = @textbox)
```

I created the selectionchangecommitted event and write their cb2.Refresh(). It's worked but cb2 is updated only if the re-select the same line. How to make the choice was single?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you try to reformulate to make it more clear to understand?

Comment: When i change cb1, cb2 updating just after double selection...